# Locate Duplicates

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, sql-update

> Disclaimer: I am still learning SQL so I apologize if my question comes off as amateur-ish or is otherwise a very simple answer. I have no formal training. I am teaching myself. Thanks.

I am looking for a proper query to locate duplicates in a table. Here's what I currently have:

> SELECT [Name]
>
> FROM [02Kids] As Tmp
> GROUP BY [Name]
> HAVING Count(*)>1
>
> order by Name asc

This works...sort of. It does return results where a specific 'Name' occurs more than once. The number of times it occurs isn't relevant though I do have a query for that too.

The problem I've run into is that this is actually part of a larger update query and while that too works, I've come to find out that my duplicates aren't all "truely" duplicates.

To be more specific, here's an example of some data pulled using a simple select query where a name is specified:

[image]

Note the CustNo column for each set of results. While the "Name" matches in each set of results, the CustNo is different for the first set. These are not truly duplicates as they do not belong to the same Customer.

Is there any way I can perform some sort of comparison to only return Names where the CustNo is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the other column into your `GROUP BY` as well:

```
SELECT [Name],[CustNo], Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM [02Kids] As Tmp
GROUP BY [Name], [CustNo]
HAVING Count(*)>1
ORDER BY [Name] ASC, [CustNo] ASC, Count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Name], [LocNo]

FROM [02Kids] As Tmp
GROUP BY [LocNo]
HAVING Count(*)>1

order by Name asc
```

Or if you can even put multiple fields in the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT [Name], [LocNo]

FROM [02Kids] As Tmp
GROUP BY [LocNo], [Name]
HAVING Count(*)>1

order by Name asc
```

You want to see the name only?

```
SELECT [Name] from
( SELECT [Name], [LockNo]
  FROM [02Kids] As Tmp
  Group BY [LocNo]
  HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: The first does not work since Name is not part of the group by and the second is not what OP wants(CustNo).

Comment: True, overlooked that one.  I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to show you all duplicates:

```
SELECT LocNo, CustNo, 02Kids.name FROM 02Kids
INNER JOIN (SELECT name FROM 02Kids
GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) > 1) dup 
ON 02Kids.name = dup.name;
```